# Using Maturin when external library is needed

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I'm trying to make a Python package from a Rust Crate I'm making. The problem is that I need the [RGSL crate](https://github.com/GuillaumeGomez/rust-GSL) which needs `libgsl0-dev` installed in the system.

I'm trying to publish using [Maturin which uses Manylinux](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin#manylinux-and-auditwheel) Docker image to build everything for Linux. The problem is that image doesn't have `libgsl0-dev` installed, so I made a custom image adding one line:

```
FROM konstin2/maturin

# To solve problems with CentOS 6 EOL 
RUN echo "https://vault.centos.org/6.10/os/x86_64/" > /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/base/mirrorlist.txt
RUN echo "http://vault.centos.org/6.10/extras/x86_64/" > /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/extras/mirrorlist.txt
RUN echo "http://vault.centos.org/6.10/updates/x86_64/" > /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/updates/mirrorlist.txt
RUN echo "http://vault.centos.org/6.10/sclo/x86_64/rh" > /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/centos-sclo-rh/mirrorlist.txt
RUN echo "http://vault.centos.org/6.10/sclo/x86_64/sclo" > /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/centos-sclo-sclo/mirrorlist.txt

# Installs needed library
RUN yum install -y libgsl0-dev

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/maturin"]
```

But when I try to build with:

`docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/io custom-image build --cargo-extra-args="--no-default-features"`

> ⚠  Warning: You're building a library without activating pyo3's
> `extension-module` feature. See
> https://pyo3.rs/v0.12.4/building_and_distribution.html#linking 
> Found pyo3 bindings  Found CPython 3.6m at python3.6, CPython 3.7m
> at python3.7, CPython 3.8 at python3.8, CPython 3.9 at python3.9
> Compiling pyo3 v0.12.4 error: could not find native static library
> `python3.6m`, perhaps an -L flag is missing

What I'm missing here? Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Comment: Try adding `py03 = { version = "whatever your using", features = ["extension-module"]}` to your Cargo.toml. I cannot re-create this error right now, but this is what I think the error message is telling you to do. Also, try looking again at the py03 readme and see if you missed anything.

Comment: Thanks for you comment! Unfortunately It didn't solve the error. It seems to be a problem with manylinux compliant, a few libraries are available for all the distributions, GSL is not one of them. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/issues/864) asking for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an user pointed me out in [this issue](https://github.com/GuillaumeGomez/rust-GSL/issues/94), there was a problem with the installed GSL version: I was using a function which was added in the last release of the library. Also I have to user the command `wheel-repair` to include some missing `.so` files. The entire process is in [this issue](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin/issues/281)